# How to dynamically update state in React.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I want to dynamically update state **CurrentIndex** whenever I select a user.Right now I am hardcoding it to 0. I want to change that.

I want to update currentIndex whenever I click on the list of users.

SidePanel contains arrays of user and its outputting firstname,lastname

```
class Home extends Component {
  state = {  
    loadUsers: [],
    currentIndex: 0,
  };

  async componentDidMount() {

    const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/users");
    this.setState({ loadUsers: res.data });
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-3" style={{ backgroundColor: "#303F9F" }}>
            <Typography variant="h6">List all Counsellors</Typography>
            {this.state.loadUsers.map((user) => {
              const { _id, firstname, lastname } = user;
              return (
                <div key={_id}>
                  <SidePanel
                    id={_id}
                    firstname={firstname}
                    lastname={lastname}
                  />
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-4">
            {this.state.loadUsers.length > 1 && (
              <div>
                <MiddlePanel
                  user={this.state.loadUsers[this.state.currentIndex]}
                />
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your code attempt to increment `this.state. currentIndex`? I don't see any handlers or logic for this in the current snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Create a handler to consume the mapped index and pass/attach handler where you need it.

```
class Home extends Component {
  state = {  
    loadUsers: [],
    currentIndex: 0,
  };

  ...

  incrementIndex = (currentIndex) => (e) => this.setState({ currentIndex });

  render() {

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-3" style={{ backgroundColor: "#303F9F" }}>
            ...
            {this.state.loadUsers.map((user, index) => {
              const { _id, firstname, lastname } = user;
              return (
                <div key={_id}>
                  <SidePanel
                    id={_id}
                    firstname={firstname}
                    lastname={lastname}
                    onClick={incrementIndex(index)} // <-- pass handler to Panel
                  />
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
          ...
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```